# Приложение React Native 0.63 не запускается на android 4.4

Tags: react-native

Ребят, привет! Делаю приложение для wonlex kt24. Там android 4.4, который kit kat , для этого поставил старую версию (0.63), где ещё была поддержка старого SDK. На эмуляторе самый стартовый проект запускается, а на часах даже не запускается, хотя apk ставится. Куда копать?

Изменение `targetSdkVersion` до 19 тоже ничего не дало.

Comment: Очень подозреваю что в сторону неполноценного андроида на часах(т.е. в специальное SDK для часов)

Comment: Туда можно закачать прочие apk и телеграм вот ставится )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все было странно просто, не ставилась именно дебаг-версия, а релизная заработала без проблем:

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```